# MySQL: Add text to a field

Tags: mysql, database

I try to solve this issue.
I want to update a `field` with a `sample text`, IF the sum of the characters of the `field` is smaller than 4.

Example:

old field = `text`

new field = `text sample text`

Thank you!

Comment: what are your options? an external program? pure sql? sql script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an `UPDATE` statement. Use `LENGTH()` function to see what's the length of the `old field` in `WHERE` clause like below

```
update table1 set `new field` = 'text sample text'
where length(`old field`) <= 4
```

Or probably

```
update table1 set `field` = CONCAT(`field`,'sample text')
where length(`field`) <= 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking for:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = 'your_value'
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(your_column) < 4
```

Comment: `CHAR_LENGTH()`! Didn't know that one. Unicode all the things! Probably better than `LENGTH()`.